# Сослагательное наклонение и глагол "бояться"

Tags: наклонение

В моем анализе насчитываются много примеров с глаголом *бояться* в комбинации с *как бы*, например:
*Она боялась, как бы она не забеременела.*

Можно из этого заключить, что в русском языке после этого глагола используется сослагательное наклонение? 
Получается, что дело в семантике этого глагола? Как ожидание, что может произоити какое-то потенциальное действие?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Она боялась, **как бы** она **не** забеременела (союз КАК БЫ НЕ).

**1) Грамматическая справка**

Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным и союзом КАК БЫ НЕ.  Основным **(нейтральным)**   союзом в придаточных такого типа является союз **ЧТО**, который можно использовать в предложении со сходной семантикой : Она боялась, что она может забеременеть.

Другие союзы имеют **дополнительное** значение: Я слышу, **как** стучит дождь (восприятие). Я сделал вид, **будто** этого не заметил (недостоверность). Я стараюсь, **чтобы** всё было хорошо (усилия, стремления, желания).

2) Союз  **КАК БЫ НЕ**  также имеет **дополнительное** значение: **опасения, страха** (глаголы бояться, остерегаться, страшиться) или **целенаправленного наблюдения** (смотреть, наблюдать):

Боюсь, **как бы** дети **не** простудились. Смотри, **как бы** не опоздать. Частица БЫ обозначает сослагательное наклонение.

**3) ВЫВОД**

Глагол бояться может сочетаться с придаточным предложением, в котором сказуемое выражено глаголом в форме изъяснительного наклонения (боюсь, что...).

Но придаточные с союзом КАК БЫ  НЕ (сослагательное наклонение)  сочетается с глаголами, имеющими ограниченную семантику: бояться, страшиться. **Такая конструкция более эмоциональна и выразительна,** она усиливает чувство опасения, уже выраженное самим глаголом.

Comment: <sigh>После исправлений.  Ну, прочтите сами свой третий параграф, начиная со слов "это СПП".  На какое предложение Вы ссылаетесь?  Которое из них - "это"?  Если разговор о предложении в начале ответа, то у меня никак не уложится в голове, где Вы в нём увидели союз ЧТО...

Comment: Вы очень эмоциональны, мсье Базаров,  пожалуйста, используйте нейтральный стиль речи - без междометий, без выражений вида "где вы это увидели", "что это за мешанина". Будьте вежливы.   И еще один момент. Как Вы считаете, автор получил ответ на свой вопрос, прочитав два предыдущих ответа? Я думаю, что нет. Здесь для понимания нужен обзор темы, и я думаю, что именно он никак не уложится в вашей голове.  А ответ такой: особая грамматическая конструкция КАК БЫ НЕ действительно связана с глаголом бояться. Это предположил автор, но с ним не согласились отвечающие.

Comment: Если бы я использовал нейтральный стиль речи, то воз и ныне был бы там.  Что невежливого Вы увидели в моём коментарии?  Укажите, исправлю(сь).  Интонацию передать в письме не так уж и просто, и многое зависит от настроения читающего. ~~~ А теперь подумайте, уважаемая Vera, стал ли Ваш ответ ***лучше*** после Вашего же редактирования?  Если не стал, тогда я виноват, что вынудил Вас Ваше драгоценное время потратить.  Но реагировать на мои замечания - Ваш собственный выбор, не забывайте об этом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ладно, мир, спасибо за критику.

Comment: Уважаемый Виктор. СПП изъяснительное может вводится не только союзом что, но и рядом других союзов, в том числе и союзом ''как бы''.  В этом Вы можете убедится, открыв любой учебник.  Советую Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников. Что касается ответа веры, это действительно придаточное изъяснительное.

Answer (score 2):

> В моем анализе насчитываются много примеров с глаголом **бояться** в
>   комбинации с **как бы**...

Во всех этих примерах перед глаголом в придаточном предложении присутствует, видимо, и отрицание ***НЕ.***

***[КАК БЫ НЕ...](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2765-2787.html#2786)***

> **§ 2786.** Употребление союза ***чтобы не*** и его лексического
>   синонима ***как бы не*** ограничено сочетаемостью со словами со
>   значениями боязни и опасения ***(бояться, опасаться, пугаться,
>   страшиться, беспокоиться, волноваться, тревожиться)*** или действий,
>   обусловленных этими чувствами ***(предостерегать, остерегаться,
>   оберегаться)***, а также словами с семантикой надзора и наблюдения
>   ***(присматривать, посматривать, поглядывать, приглядывать, смотреть, караулить).***
>
> Сообщение, оформляемое союзами ***чтобы не*** и ***как бы не***,
>   имеет характер предположения, а описываемая в нем ситуация оценивается
>   как нежелательная. Придаточное предложение имеет форму сослагат. накл.
>   или инфинитивной конструкции: *Боюсь, как бы так не заболеть, что и в
>   Россию не попадешь* (С.-Щ., переписка); *Ко мне Вера Григорьевна не
>   зашла, возвратясь из-за границы, из опасения, как бы Федя не
>   пострадал* (С.-Щ., переписка); *Матушка с беспокойством посмотрела на
>   меня. Я отошел немножко в сторону, из предосторожности, как бы меня не
>   выслали* (Тург.); *Поглядывай, чтоб кто коней не увел!* (Чех.);
>   *Одного боюсь - за вас и сам, - чтоб не обмелели наши души* (Маяк.)
>
> Способность к совместному употреблению с союзами ***чтобы не*** и
>   ***как бы не*** обнаруживает глагол ***думать*** в знач. ***(предполагать)***: *Так к году Лев-отец не шуткой думать стал, Чтобы сынка невежей не оставить* (Крыл.). В экспрессивной речи в круг
>   слов с семантикой опасения могут вовлекаться слова, способные в
>   контексте обозначать другие виды отрицательных эмоций и поведения:
>   *Ребятишки прослышали про эту науку... Спозаранку ревут, как бы к Прокопьичу не попасть* (Бажов).
>
> Примечание. В литературе XIX в. в официальной, книжной речи
>   употреблялся союз ***дабы не***, к настоящему времени устаревший:
>   *Благородные для того не сближаются с простым народом, что боятся, дабы не увидали, что они еще хуже его* (Лерм.).

Answer (score 1):

После глагола "боятся" не всегда используется согласительное наклонение. Ср.: Она боялась, что пойдет дождь. Он боялся, что она не придет. В этих предложениях нет сослагательного наклонения.

Answer (score 0):

Вы так говорите, будто после глагола ***бояться*** всегда должно употребляться сослагательное наклонение. Это ведь чушь. Можно ещё чего-то или кого-то бояться: «Он боялся мамы». А употребление, которое вы привели в примерах, в русском языке действительно возможны. И семантику вы тоже верно определили.

Comment: я хотела сказать, глагол "бояться" в комбинации с придаточным предложением... мне понятно, что если после глагола следует существительное, то оно не может стоять ни в каком наклонении...